# Add Json Creator to 3rd party library with final class that use a builder

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I need use Jackson to deserialize a final class without a default constructor of a third-party library. Instances of the class are constructed via a builder.

I may use `@JsonCreator` because is an external library, but I can't use `MixIn` because is a final class...

I have tried adding a new `JsonDeserializer`, which instantiates the object using the builder but Jackson does not populate any of the object's fields after creation.

Is there any way to add an "external" `JsonCreator` or create a `JsonDeserializer` which, after instantiating the object, uses a default mechanism to populate the object's fields?

This is the deserializer:

```kotlin
class BlockDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Block>() {      
    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): Block {         
       return Block.builder().build()
   }  
}
```

I need add "something" to populate the block before return it.

Comment: Can you share your attempt with `JsonDeserializer`? I think this is too abstract as currently presented to be answerable.

Comment: ```class BlockDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Block>() {

    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): Block {
        return Block.builder().build()

    }
}```

Yes, I know that need "something" to populate the data. The question is "how" can use the default method to populate it.

Comment: Please update your question with the code instead of adding a comment.

Comment: The magic "something" is to actually _use_ the `JsonParser` and call setter methods on the builder before calling `build`. What have you tried? There's not much more that can be said without knowing anything about the data structure or the object you're trying to build.